# Hiding lines from getting displayed

Tags: linux, command-line

Can anybody tell me how to hide an error output.

For example.

I want to hide the below lines from getting displayed on command line.

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

or a way I could store this in a file.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: look like a script run wild, you might have `grep $var1 $var2` and `$var1` and `$var2` don't have proper value. this will generate the usage message you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Each process gets two default file descriptors: `stdout` and `stderr`. The shell, normally `bash`, handles redirection of these. Most shells output both to the console unless they are redirected.

In bash (and most other shells, really) `>` and `|` redirects and pipes `stdout`, while `2>` redirects `stderr`, the second file descriptor.

If we would like to just disregard something, we can redirect it to the special node `/dev/null`.

So the answer is: `grep 2> /dev/null`

If you would like to store it in a file, just redirect to a filename:
`grep 2> stderr.txt`